# Conversion from Markdown to HTML in Django project

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-markdown

I'm on a project which include use of Python, Django, HTML and Markdown. I have to develop a site similar to wikipedia, in fact the project is called encyclopedia. My goal is to make visiting / wiki / TITLE, where TITLE is the title of an encyclopedia entry, to display a page that displays the content of that encyclopedia entry. The encyclopedia entries are CSS Django Git HTML Python (each entry has its own .md file). the problem I have is with the "markdown" library. In practice, I was able to convert the syntax from markdown to HTML but as output I only receive the tags in written format, without them applying their standard style to the content inside them. I am attaching the code I wrote for the conversion and a screenshot of the output I receive.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import markdown

from . import util


def index(request):
  return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
      "entries": util.list_entries()
  })

def entry(request, title):
  content = util.get_entry(title)
  if content == None:
      content = markdown.markdown(f'## {title.capitalize()}\'s page has not been 
      found')
content = markdown.markdown(content)
return render(request, f"encyclopedia/entry.html", {
    'title': title,
    'content': content
})
```

[image]

Comment: Share the template...

Comment: use httpResponse instead of render. https://vegibit.com/render-html-in-django-without-a-template/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable escaping the rendered HTML content, by using the [**`|safe`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe):

```
{{ content|safe }}
```